# Do I need to pay for Kendo-UI If I made site using it

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui

Sorry, if this is going non-relevant to this forums.

Suppose I want to make a site in Kendo-UI then is this a free stuff (open-source) or I need to pay for it.

From the download page it's look like it's not  available for free http://www.kendoui.com/download.aspx.

The free stuff is only for desktop kind of thing. Can someone make me clear that I should need to pay them to make site in kendo-mobile UI

My means to freely avilable for mobile site development or not.

Comment: I need to know for mobile version of kenod-ui

Comment: I can't say for sure if it has some sort of method of imprinting whether or not your site was used with a free trial/license in use that could be traced back or cause legal problems. But the fact that it only has a 30-day trial and a purchase option, I would assume you have to pay (to be on the safe side).

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about licensing of a product, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use Kendo UI mobile, then you have to buy a license. The Kendo UI web controls are released open sources under a GPL license, but this does not include Kendo UI mobile.

So yes you have to pay for Kendo UI Mobile.

Comment: Yeah, I have contact them through mail and their answer is the license is developer based (not site) so I need to buy a license for myself.

Comment: Is this still valid? `http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core` mentions about open-source KendoUI Core library

Comment: Yes it is still valid by August 2015 :-)

Comment: According to their website it's still valid.

Answer (score 13):

I found a Kendo Forum [answer](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/general-discussions/open-source-license-gplv3.aspx#2055583) to a post by an Administrator which may shed some light.

> The opensource edition of Kendo UI Web is a suitable option if you are
>   building an application for internal use or an open source application
>   with a license compatible with the GNU GPL v3.
>
> If your application will in any way **contain commercial, non-open
>   source pieces** which do not comply with the GPL license, or you are
>   interested in Support and/or access to minor updates through the year,
>   then you will need to use the Commercial version of Kendo UI Web.
>
> However, due to the complexity of the GPL and the ambiguities inherent
>   in copyright law, **it is not appropriate for us to advise you** on your
>   specific licensing decisions. The best and safest choice is to contact
>   legal counsel so that you are sure of getting the rights you need.

Comment: Thanks Quinton for pointing out that link. However, my situation is a little bit different. I am building a campus website and it's source code is free/open. But in future, i am planning to add advertisements to the website to make money. Am i eligible to use kendo ui web? I think this doesn't contradict GPL.

Comment: or just buy the license lol